# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Individual User Accounts without HTTPs

Tags: https, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.1, user-accounts

The ASP.NET Core 2.1 new template with Individual User Accounts cannot be created  without HTTPs. There is anyway around this?

Answer (score 0):

You should always use HTTPS and never HTTP. HTTP is insecure for a number of reasons. That is probably way it is not possible.